# How to add a different background color to bottom navigation tab selected item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

I need to add a different background color i.e a grey color as in the below pictures(Click on the blue texts to view), to the current selected tab in bottom navigation. I am using the default navigation tab activity without the help of any libraries.

[bottom navigation active tab highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMSTF.jpg)

[second active tab highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha5kx.jpg)

Here is code for bottom navigation view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_Userview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemBackground="@color/ActivityBackgroundColor"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_item_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_item_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation1"/>
```

Here is my code for navigation item selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:color="@color/Buttoncolor" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="@color/TextColor" android:state_checked="false" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this library can help you

[NavigationTabBar](https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabBar)

in gradle(app)

```
compile 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
```

simply add this in your xml file

```
 <devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar
    android:id="@+id/navigationTabBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
    app:ntb_animation_duration="400"
    app:ntb_titled="true"
    app:ntb_scaled="true"
    app:ntb_tinted="true"
    app:ntb_bg_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:ntb_active_color="@color/colorAccent"
    app:ntb_inactive_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:ntb_title_mode="all"
    app:ntb_swiped="true"
    app:ntb_icon_size_fraction="0.4"
    app:ntb_title_size="@dimen/littleFontSize"/>
```

**UPDATE**

you can create selector name backgrand_nav_item.xml like below

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" 
           android:state_checked="true"/>
     <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"
           android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

and your BottomNavigationView

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation_Userview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
app:itemBackground="@drawable/backgrand_nav_item"
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_item_selector"
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_item_selector"
app:menu="@menu/navigation1"/>
```

Comment: Can we achieve this without using any third party libraries ??

Comment: yes , your code is correct, what wrong with your code??

Comment: Actually what i meant is that can we change the background of active tab without using any third party libraries,i need to know how ??